# Postgres string formatting for record ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a table to keep an archive of dad jokes in Postgres. For the `title` record, I would like the value to by-default be the joke ID, but formatted in a way where if the `id` is 7, the record's title is `Joke #7`. Here is my query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.jokes (
    id int NOT null primary KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    title varchar NULL DEFAULT FORMAT("Joke #%s", ), -- the title that I would like to be formatted
    body varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT jokes_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public."Users"(id)
);
```

Comment: From here [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):  " DEFAULT default_expr ... The value is any variable-free expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed). Subqueries are not allowed either. ... ". You will need a trigger to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a trigger function that will change the title if it is not set

```
create function change_title() returns trigger as $$
  begin 
     if new.title is null then
         new.title := format('joke #%s', new.id);
     end if;     
     return new; 
  end; $$ language plpgsql; 

create trigger change_title_jokes before insert on jokes for each row execute procedure change_title();
```

Demo in [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/b8cb09e8)